# How to disable Anti forgery cookie for .NET 8 web app?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, blazor

I am trying to disable all Anti forgery cookies in my .NET 8 Blazor web app. I added this in Program.cs:

```
app.MapRazorComponents<App>()
.DisableAntiforgery()
.AddInteractiveServerRenderMode();
```

I then removed the UseAntiforgery() line:

```
    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseAuthorization();
   //app.UseAntiforgery();
```

But this does not work, I am still seeing the cookie being written:

[image]

What else do I need to do? Thanks for any advice!

Comment: Why do you want to disable them? They're an essential part of security on the web today.

Comment: Calling `.DisableAntiforgery()` on `MapRazorComponents<>` only affects Blazor - not the rest of ASP.NET Core.

Comment: To turn off validation you can do something like: builder.Services.AddRazorPages().AddRazorPagesOptions(o =>
              {
                  o.Conventions.ConfigureFilter(new IgnoreAntiforgeryTokenAttribute());
              });

Comment: @browsermator i've added your codes and it did not work, still writing cookie.

Comment: yeah I think it'll just turn off the validation.  I wouldn't worry about that cookie, it'll only be written once per session methinks.  What's the use-case, btw?  Is this for development only?

Comment: The reason I am trying this is that I am testing to put my site in an iFrame and it doesn't work. I have to enable third-party cookie to make it work. So I am trying to eliminate all cookies and make my site working in a iFrame.

Comment: sounds like the x-frame-options header that will be added by default.  (for security) See option "SuppressXFrameOptionsHeader": https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.antiforgery.antiforgeryoptions?view=aspnetcore-8.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to disable this Antiforgery cookie, I suggest you could modify the AddAntiforgery method's Cookie.Expiration to zero. According to the document, you could find, the blazor template will add the Antiforgery middleware automatically, so you could just modify the cookie expire time, since this middleware will set the cookie automatically.

More details, you could refer to below codes:

1.call the Antiforgery service:

```
builder.Services.AddAntiforgery(options =>
{     // Set Cookie properties using CookieBuilder properties†.
    
    options.Cookie.Expiration = TimeSpan.Zero;
    
});
```

2.Set the middleware:

```
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.UseAntiforgery();
app.UseStaticFiles();


app.MapRazorComponents<App>().DisableAntiforgery().AddInteractiveServerRenderMode();
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: This seems to be working! I will do more testing, thanks Mr. Zhang 